# SWIG/Scilab: RuntimeError: the module is not initialized

Tags: user-interface, scilab

I get this error message despite that IPCV module is loaded at the start: SWIG/Scilab: RuntimeError: the module is not initialized . Here is my code:

```
f=figure('figure_position',[400,50],'figure_size',[640,480],'auto_resize','on','background',[33],'figure_name','Figure n°%d','dockable','off','infobar_visible','off','toolbar_visible','off','menubar_visible','off','default_axes','on','visible','off');
//////////
handles.dummy = 0;
handles.fct1= newaxes();handles.fct1.margins = [ 0 0 0 0];handles.fct1.axes_bounds = [0.099359,0.0909091,0.3028846,0.1136364];


f.visible = "on";
im=imread('fct1.png');
imshow(im);
```

Comment: What is your operating system, version of scilab and version of ipcv ?

Comment: I am on windows 10 , Scilab 6.0.2 and ipcv 4.1.2

Comment: I had the same issue loading the demo_filter1.sci demo. I can't find SWIG mentioned in filenames or directories. Have you had any luck? Edit: just realized this is an old question.

Answer (score 0):

For people who wants to try *sciTorch Toolbox* (or other toolboxes) for Scilab. I've got into the same situation, it's probably because of library collision/confusion. So, I removed the `IPCV` and the other toolboxes and installed `sciTorch` again then everything worked fine.